# assign variable to img src

Tags: javascript, html, image, variables, src

I have a variable that I cannot edit, named reg0001, which is coming from firmware on a board that I am using.  reg0001 is either a 0 or 1, and I would like to make a page that updates live, which shows a green img if reg0001 is 0, or red if it is 1.  Here is what I have so far.

```
<div id="Oobj6"style="position:absolute;left:270px;top:60px;width:20px;height:53px;overflow:hidden;">
<input type="text" id="Gform4" class="Body-C" name="reg0001" value="%d" >
<div>
<img id="Ggeo1" src="whitelight.jpg" alt="" name="state1">
</div>
```

and javascript:

```
function updateChart() {
    var x;
    if (isIE) { // for Internet Explorer

    x = parseInt(document.getElementById("reg0001").value);
    if (x == 0) { 
        document.state1.src = "greenlight.jpg";
        }
    else {
        document.state1.src = "redlight.jpg";
    }
```

right now this script works, but I have to keep refreshing the page to get the images to change, even if reg0001 changed in the background.  I don't know much about javascript, I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: `setInterval(updateChart, 1000)`? This will call your function every second. But how is your input field updated?

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop it with `SetInterval`:

```
 updateChart();
 setInterval(updateChart, 5000); //Cycles every 5 seconds
```

If you need to manage the cycling, you can record the interval Id that `SetInterval` generates:

```
 var intervalId = setInterval(function().... //Mindful about the scope of intervalId here!
```

Then later on you can stop cycling with `clearInterval`:

```
 clearInterval(intervalId);
```

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval

Comment: @putvande It was a copy and paste answer! The original code had multiple statements where I needed to wrap it in a function.

Answer (score 1):

setinterval for it

```
setInterval(updateChart, 5000);
```

it will call `updateChart` after each **5s**
update this in your `updateChart`

```
x = parseInt(document.getElementById("reg0001").value,10);
```

or

```
x = Number(document.getElementById("reg0001").value);
```

to update value

```
document.getElementById("reg0001").value="2"
```

bettter way according to OP need

js

```
setInterval(updateChart, 5000);
var x=true;
function updateChart() {

    if (isIE) { // for Internet Explorer
    if (x) { 
        document.state1.src = "greenlight.jpg";
        x=false; 
        }
    else {
        document.state1.src = "redlight.jpg";
        x=false; 
        }
    }
}
//no need for getting any value if you just want animation
```

Comment: I just added this, but it still doesn't seem to be changing. do I also need to be updating my input field?

Comment: @user3768868 you can do also without the input feild value, see the updated code

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do

```
var tId;
window.onload=function() {
  tId = setInterval(function() {
    var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("reg0001").value,10);
    document.state1.src = x == 0?"greenlight.jpg":"redlight.jpg";
  },5000);
}
```

If you do not update the field reg0001 from somewhere else, there is no point. So perhaps you need to use AJAX to get the value